# Spatial verification process

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working on a project that involves mapping community anchor institutions and at a point where I need to verify that the points are in the correct parcels.
I have the address information for the point file and some of the address info for the parcel layer as well. 
The institutions have a Name field and the parcels have an owner field. 
I also have the parcel Id tied to the points through a spatial join. My intention is to

1. Select points and parcels that have the same ID
2. From those with matching IDs select the records that have matching name and owner name
3. From the matching IDs and Names select the records that have matching address information.

This will likely leave me with around 4,000 points to verify spatial accuracy.

I am looking for any ideas of how to automate this task.

I have a little experience with python but not much so it would be best if the solution would not be terribly complex but sound.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly straightforward task with a SQL query in the attribute table:

Your data can be queried to return records that have `field1 = field2`. From that, you can choose `Select from current selection` those records which have `field3 = field4`. From this selection, you again choose `Select from current selection` those records which have `field5 = field6`. Repeat *ad nauseam*.

Luckily, these steps can be combined with the `AND` keyword, like so: `field1 = field2 AND field3 = field4 AND field5 = field6`.

This is pretty simple with arcpy as well (you can run this directly in the python window of Arcmap-- a new layer containing the selection will be added to the TOC; it can then be saved to disk):

```py
sql = "field1 = field2 AND field3 = field4 AND field5 = field6"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("name of layer", "TO VERIFY", sql)
```